# toggle button moves a little up and down

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF snippet like this

```xhtml
<p:panel>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <!--(other components here)-->
        <h:panelGroup id="locked1" layout="block">
            <p:outputLabel id="labelp1" for="password1" value="Password:" style="width:100px;" 
                rendered="#{!myMB.showPassword}"/>  
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="locked2" layout="block">
            <p:password redisplay="true" id="password1" value="#{myMB.decryptedPassword}" 
                rendered="#{!myMB.showPassword}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="locked3" layout="block">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-unlocked" action="#{myMB.togglePassword}" 
                rendered="#{!myMB.showPassword}" 
                update="locked1,locked2,locked3,unlocked1,unlocked2,unlocked3"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup id="unlocked1" layout="block">
            <p:outputLabel id="labelp2" for="password2" value="Password:" 
                style="width:100px;" rendered="#{myMB.showPassword}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="unlocked2" layout="block">
            <p:inputText id="password2" value="#{myMB.decryptedPassword}"              
                rendered="#{myMB.showPassword}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="unlocked3" layout="block">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-locked" action="#{myMB.togglePassword}"     
                rendered="#{myMB.showPassword}" 
                update="locked1,locked2,locked3,unlocked1,unlocked2,unlocked3"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <!--(other components here)-->
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

It works, but when I click the button to "toggle" the password, it seems that there's a very very small height difference, so it appears to "move" a little inside the form up and down.

Of course, the first thing I've tried was two panels, but since it's a 3-column layout, it was breaking it.

How do I fix this?

Less stupid solutions than mine are welcome :-)

TIA

UPDATE I am testing in primefaces 4, firefox 24

Some screenshots below

before toggle

[image]

after toggle

[image]

custom css

```
    body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-inputfield {
    width:300px;
}
.clean td{
    border: 0;
    background:#ffffff;
}
.clean tr{
    border: 0;
    background:#ffffff;
}
.clean{
    border: 0;
    background:#ffffff;
}

/* smaller fonts - careful not to be too small or it will mess up p:menuitem*/

.ui-widget {
    font-size: 90%;
 }
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 100%;
 }
 .ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 90% !important;
 }
```

Comment: Can you add screenshots and detail more your problem?

Comment: You don't tell about Primefaces version, tested browsers, if there's extra CSS.. That's impossible to answer without that.

Comment: platform details and screenshots added. thanks

Comment: Does it provide focus to the field? Could this be some fancy padding and illumination that is provided by any particular web browser?

Comment: good point @XtremeBiker. CSS customizations added to the question (although the font size difference - using 90% sometimes, does not seems to be the cause here). I am also using "black-tie" primefaces.THEME